# Javascript switch issue with url domains

Tags: javascript, html

The javascript code below has a problem at the switch statement it does not pick up the domain from the url.

Can someone explain why?

I want the the code to create a redirect url base on the domain from the received one, and limit that to the domains at the `api` array.

```js
$(function(a,api){ api = ['.com', '.net', '.org', '.info', '.pro', '.online', '.web', '.xyz', '.me', '.network', 'index.html', 'cloudfront.tubi.video', '.mp4', 'playlist.m3u8', 'index.m3u8', 'master.m3u8', '.m3u8', 'ok.ru', 'drive.google.com', 'docs.google.com', 'photos.google.com', 'hdviet.com', 'vimeo.com', 'tv.zing.vn', 'mp3.zing.vn', 'youtube.com', 'dailymotion.com/video/', 'dailymotion.com/embed/video/', 'dai.ly', 'facebook.com', 'imdb.com', 'v.youku.com', 'qq.com', 'v.qq.com', 'v.pptv.com', 'tv.sohu.com', 'vip.1905.com', 'iqiyi.com', 'www.iqiyi.com', 'nhaccuatui.com/vh/', 'nhaccuatui.com/video/', 'avi', '=m18', '=m22', '=m37', 'fembed.com', 'feurl.com', 'playhydrax.com', 'fsharetv.com', 'blogspot.com', 'googleusercontent.com', 'vanlong.stream', 'webm', 'nguontv.com', '-iqiyi.com', 'www.iqiyi.com', '-youku.com', '.ink', 'mixdrop.co', '.to', 'phim-homnay.net', 'open.tube'];
 a = "https://vimeo.com/323242237";
  for (var i in api) {
    if(a !== 0){
       var ab, domain = '';
        if (domain !== -1) {domain = api[i]};
        switch (domain) {
          case (domain == "-youku.com" || domain == "-iqiyi.com" || domain == "playlist.m3u8" || domain == "index.m3u8" || domain == "master.m3u8" || domain == ".m3u8" || domain == ".mp4" || domain == "googleusercontent.com" || domain == "blogspot.com" || domain == "=m18" || domain == "=m22" || domain == "=m37"):
            ab = "/p/mp4.html?url=" + a + "";
            break;
          case (domain == "youtube.com"):
            ab = "/youtube.class.php?url=" + a + "";
            break;
          case (domain == "facebook.com"):
            ab = "/p/facebook.html?url=" + a + "";
            break;
          case (domain == "dailymotion.com"):
            ab = "/p/dailymotion.html?url=" + a + "";
            break;
          case (domain == "vimeo.com"):
            ab = "/p/vimeo.html?url=" + a + "";
            break;
          case (domain == "ok.ru"):
            ab = "/p/ok_20.html?id=" + a + "";
            break;

          default:
            ab = "default/" + a + "";
            break
        } 
  }
   document.write("<br/>2....."+ab)
   break;
  }
});
```

```html
 <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your issue in the post and wrap the code up in a code block? `\`\`\``

Comment: The code you posted always is going to return the default case because you are never really extracting the domain to then compare it at your switch

Comment: I want the link attached to it to work properly with the redirected domain name in the switch and be limited to domains ending in [api]. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted always is going to return the default case because you are never really extracting the domain to then compare it at your switch

There is an npm package: psl (Public Suffix List), you can use to do that extraction that is already taking in consideration all rules and providing functions to retrieve the portion of the domain you want

```
npm install --save psl
```

you can also do the script import:

```
<script src="psl.min.js"></script>
```

and then extract the domain from your url:

```
var psl = require('psl');
var parsed = psl.parse('www.google.com');
console.log(parsed.tld); // 'com'
console.log(parsed.sld); // 'google'
console.log(parsed.domain); // 'google.com'
console.log(parsed.subdomain); // 'www'
```

At your code I would extract the domain from the url just before the switch comparison:

```
var psl = require('psl');
url = "https://vimeo.com/323242237";
var parsed = psl.parse(url);
domain = parsed.domain;

switch (domain) {
          ...
          case (domain == "vimeo.com"):
          ...
}
```

you can find more documentation here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/psl

Comment: Thank you for guiding me

Comment: No problem, hopefully it will help, welcome to the community!